# NSDateFormatter wrong string after formatting

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdateformatter

I receive a date through a string parameter, which is tempDateString, in a [day month year] format (for ex. 01 05 2005):

```
 NSLog(@"tempdatestring %@", tempDateString);
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM YYYY"];
 NSDate *dayDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tempDateString];
 NSLog(@"daydate %@", dayDate);
```

My problem is, that the two logs don't match. The outputs are:

```
tempdatestring 04 10 2012
daydate 2011-12-24 22:00:00 +0000
```

What should I change at the date formatter's date format, to get the good date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2 Problems

- your format is wrong it is `@"dd MM yyyy"` **case sensitive**
- Use timezone to get the correct value[GMT value]

  ```
  NSString *tempDateString=@"04 10 2012" ;
  NSLog(@"tempdatestring %@", tempDateString);
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy"];
  NSDate *dayDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tempDateString];
  NSLog(@"daydate %@", dayDate);
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem: the casesensivity of the year. I'm a litte bit surprised, because in an other Utility class, where I'm using the date formatting too, I'm using with "YYYY" and it works fine. But it's good to know. :)

Comment: yep case sensitivity for me. Thanks @LithuT.V

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `%@` format specifier, the return value of the `-description` method invoked on the provided object is used.

`NSDate`'s `-description` method outputs its value in that specific way.

Your *real* problem though is that your date format string is incorrect - it should be `dd MM yyyy`.

I stuck this in a sample Xcode project:

```
NSString *s = @"04 11 2012";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy"];
NSDate *d = [df dateFromString:s];
NSDateComponents *c = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:d];
NSLog(@"%@", c);
```

It gave me the following output:

```
2012-10-04 01:53:24.320 dftest[59564:303] <NSDateComponents: 0x100113e70>
    Calendar Year: 2012
    Month: 11
    Leap month: no
    Day: 4
```

Comment: Okay, but even if I turn the date back to string, with stringFromDate method, I receive the same string, displayed below. I changed the date format to DD MM YYYY, but there isn't any change, displays the wrong date.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy"];
NSDate *dayDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tempDateString];
NSLog(@"daydate %@", dayDate);
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dayDate];
NSLog(@"strDate :%@",strDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[form setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy"];
form.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-7200.0];
NSDate *dayDate = [form dateFromString:@"05 10 2012"];
NSLog(@"daydate %@", dayDate);
NSString *strDate = [form stringFromDate:dayDate];
NSLog(@"strDate %@",strDate);
```

Change date format to `@"dd MM yyyy"`. After this, dateFromString may still parse the wrong date (in my case it was yesterday 21-00). To avoid this I've set TimeZone in my DateFormatter:

```
form.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-7200.0];
```

-7200.0 is my timezone, you should change this to yours ("0" sets to Greenwich). After this log looks like:

```
daydate 2012-10-05 02:00:00 +0000
strDate 05 10 2012
```

Comment: 2 *seconds* from GMT? Really? Are you in Greenwich? LOL

Comment: Whops :)) Took this from some old project, no idea why 2.0, my zone is -7200.0 :) Thanks